# 500 error coming when I run my ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC and trying out the ajax functionality on my website. Whenever, I run my ajax function it returns 500 in alert. 
This is my controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonNewsfeed(int id)
{
    var db = new dekhosaleEntities1();
    sale s = db.sales.First(m => m.sale_id == id);
    List<sale> sale1 = db.sales.ToList();
    saleviewmodel model = new saleviewmodel
    {
        currentsale = s,
        Sales = sale1
    };
    return Json(model);  
}
```

This is my Jquery ajax function

```
$('.b1').click(function () {
    $.ajax({      
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '@Url.Action("JsonNewsfeed", "Home")',
        data:"{ id: 5}", 
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);  
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.status);  
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: `data: { id: 5},` WIthout `"`

Comment: still giving the same error

Comment: A 500 error means it is an issue on your server. Check your server logs for clues.

Comment: I am working on local host

Comment: It means you server is throwing an exception. Debug your code. And use your browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the response - it will give you the details of the error message. Most likely its because `.First(m => m.sale_id == id)` throws an exception because there are no elements with `sale_id == id` (and it needs to be `data: { id: 5 }`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct you ajax request ...
like URL...(url: 'Url.Action("JsonNewsfeed", "Home")') 
data (data: {id:id}) (if needed check that too)

here is the reference..

> Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: it seems like there is a problem in URL but i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: and yes try like this... "/Home/JsonNewsFeed" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult JsonNewsfeed(int id)
{
    try 
    {
      ....logic here....
      return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO: log exception
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

you could also return like this instead:

```
return Content(jsonObject.ToString(), "application/json");
```

or

```
return Content("Your message",...
```

Then in your ajax call change the success to:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/someDir/someAjaxControllerMethod",
        data: jStr,
        success: function (json) {
            ...do something...
            var s = JSON.stringify(json);
            alert(s);
        },
        error: function (event) {
            alert(event.statusText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Now the alert says not found

Comment: try messing with the url and the data you are sending, there may be something incorrect about the way you have used it. Like instead of using '@Url.Action("JsonNewsfeed", "Home")' try maybe "/Home/JsonNewsFeed" and you may need to mess around with either stringify or parse on the data you are sending with the ajax call.

Comment: Yes there was something wrong with url. Thank you :)

Comment: I just returned a string from the controller and tried to to @url.action(jsonnewsfeed,Home) and added data like data: {id=id} and it worked

Comment: awesome! I am glad you got it.